# Получить id строки, по которой кликнули

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp

Имеется следующий код:

```
<div id="content">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Номер</th>
            <th>Наименование</th>
            <th>Описание</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
            <tr onclick="show('block')">
                <td>${product.id}</td>
                <td>${product.name}</td>
                <td>${product.description}</td>
                <td>${product.price}</td>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
    </table>


</div>
```

Как получить id нажатой строки таблицы и вывести его хотя бы в алерт?

Comment: Причем тут java?

Comment: @PavelMayorov c:forEach - это же вроде директива из Java Server Pages?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight jsp != java

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight поставил [tag:jsp]

Answer (score 1):

На чистом js

```js
var row = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

[].forEach.call(row, function(elem){
    elem.addEventListener('click', function (el) { 
        alert(this.children[0].innerHTML);  
    })
});
```

```html
<div id="content">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Номер</th>
            <th>Наименование</th>
            <th>Описание</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>name 1</td>
            <td>desc 1</td>
            <td>price 1</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>name 2</td>
            <td>desc 2</td>
            <td>price 2</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>name 3</td>
            <td>desc 3</td>
            <td>price 3</td>
        </tr>


    </table>


</div>
```

На jquery

```js
$('tr').on('click', function(){
  alert($(this).children('td:first-child').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Номер</th>
            <th>Наименование</th>
            <th>Описание</th>
            <th>Цена</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>name 1</td>
            <td>desc 1</td>
            <td>price 1</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>name 2</td>
            <td>desc 2</td>
            <td>price 2</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>name 3</td>
            <td>desc 3</td>
            <td>price 3</td>
        </tr>


    </table>


</div>
```

Comment: Можете написать ответ конкретно с учетом моего кода? Ведь у меня автоматически генерируются строки, исходя из количества данных в БД.Желательно на js

Comment: @Mishustiq ну так всё то же самое будет

Answer (score 0):

Если в лоб, средствами jquery то так:

```
...
<tr onclick="alert($(this).find('td').first().text());">
...
```

т.е. показываем значение первой колонки в строке. Вообще лучше id положить в атрибут какой-нибудь

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ //Стартует по загрузке
    $('#tblExport td').click(function(){// Запускаем по клику на ячейке.
        //Узнаем индекс строки + индекс ячейки таблицы
        alert( 'Вы нажали  '+$(this).parent('tr').index()+ ' строку');
    });
});
```

Comment: Ответ неверный, потому что используется неправильный язык программирования